# Select a range in other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have three sheets:

- Hoja1
- Hoja2
- Hoja3

In each sheet there are two columns from A1:Bsomthing. It varies from sheet to sheet.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I managed to verify my LastRow Code and my LastColumn Code are working. I painted them to make sure its okay.

When I try to paint the Range(Cells(2, LastColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)), I want to paint Column C till last row of column B0, it gives me an error 438.

[image]

```vb
Public Sub ponerAlgoEnCadaHoja()

Dim LastRowVisibleCategorie As Integer
Dim VisibleCategorieList As Range
Dim VC As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim RecategorizeListRange As Range

LastRowVisibleCategorie = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Set VisibleCategorieList = Range(Cells(2, "E"), Cells(LastRowVisibleCategorie, "E"))

For Each VC In VisibleCategorieList
    LastRowVC = Sheets(VC.Value).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Sheets(VC.Value).Cells(LastRowVC, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    LastColumnVC = Sheets(VC.Value).Cells(2, "A").End(xlToRight).Column + 1
   Sheets(VC.Value).Cells(2, LastColumnVC).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    
    Set RecategorizeListRange = Sheets(VC.Value).Range(Cells(2, LastColumnVC), Cells(LastRowVC, LastColumnVC))
    Sheets(VC.Value).RecategorizeListRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `Sheets(VC.Value).` from the start of that line.

Comment: So I understand I was repeating code there, I removed it.
Now it give me error 1004 on de line just before. The one with the Set RecategorizeListRange.

Comment: This is probably the most frequent question on here - you need to specify the sheet for both the `Range` and `Cells` calls: `Set RecategorizeListRange = Sheets(VC.Value).Range(Sheets(VC.Value).Cells(2, LastColumnVC), Sheets(VC.Value).Cells(LastRowVC, LastColumnVC))`

Comment: Woow may be it is, but for me ur a genious! haha thank you. your answer will make a before and after on my vba coding. Thanks!!